# Tensorflow 1.10.0 Java API: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to use uninitialized value

Tags: java, python, tensorflow, gpu

I'm developing a plugin for ImageJ that would use Tensorflow Java API (and GPU) to:

- restore a model, trained using Tensorflow Python API, **and**
- run inference for a provided data

The model seems to get restored fine and the error is got when running the inference:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to use uninitialized value rv_stage1_out
```

Where **rv_stage1_out** is a Variable. The one special feature of the network, that might be causing the error, is it consists of 2 stages - in the 1st stage the data is run through of a bunch of identical networks, the result is stored in **rv_stage1_out** (which stays in the GPU memory to avoid unnecessary I/O) which is then used in the second (and final) run.

Technically it does not have to be initialized (but there's this check for uninitialized variables and it's probably valid)... but even if I wanted to initialize it in Java there seems to be no way of doing it. I have only found [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813989/how-to-create-initialize-a-variable-with-tensorflow-1-0-java-api#43190488) but it only works for new variables.

At the same, restoring the model and running inference **works in** Tensorflow Python API.

#### More details and logs

- Python: the model is a **SavedModel** (*.pb) , see [infer_qcds_graph_01.py](https://github.com/Elphel/python3-imagej-tiff/blob/master/infer_qcds_graph_01.py):

  ```
  ...
  builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(dirs['exportdir'])
  ...
  builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess,[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING])
  builder.save(False)
  ```
- Python: the very same script restores the model and runs inference w/o errors. Probably because of running variable initializers:

  ```
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
  ```
- Java: the model is restored using **SavedModelBundle**, see [TensorflowExamplePlugin.java](https://git.elphel.com/Elphel/imagej-elphel/blob/gpu/src/main/java/TensorflowExamplePlugin.java):

  ```
  final SavedModelBundle bundle = SavedModelBundle.load(EXPORTDIR,"serve");
  ```

  log:

  ```
  2018-09-18 13:18:24.005779: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:113] Restoring SavedModel bundle.
  2018-09-18 13:18:24.015907: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:148] Running LegacyInitOp on SavedModel bundle.
  2018-09-18 13:18:24.015956: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:233] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: success. Took 708712 microseconds.
  ```
- Java: getting the error when running the inference:

  code:

  ```
  bundle.session().runner()
        .feed("ph_corr2d",toTensor2DFloat(img_corr2d, tensorsToClose))
        .feed("ph_target_disparity",toTensor2DFloat(img_target, tensorsToClose)
        .feed("ph_ntile",toTensor1DInt(img_ntile, tensorsToClose))
        .fetch("Disparity_net/stage1done:0")
        .run()
        .get(0);
  ```

  log:

  ```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to use uninitialized value rv_stage1_out
           [[Node: Disparity_net/update = ScatterUpdate[T=DT_FLOAT, Tindices=DT_INT32, use_locking=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](rv_stage1_out, _arg_ph_ntile_0_1/_37, Disparity_net/g_fc_sub5/Maximum)]]
          at org.tensorflow.Session.run(Native Method)
          at org.tensorflow.Session.access$100(Session.java:48)
          at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.runHelper(Session.java:298)
          at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.run(Session.java:248)
          at TensorflowExamplePlugin.main(TensorflowExamplePlugin.java:196)
          at TensorflowExamplePlugin.run(TensorflowExamplePlugin.java:63)
          at Eyesis_Correction.runMenuCommand(Eyesis_Correction.java:4754)
          at Eyesis_Correction.<init>(Eyesis_Correction.java:663)
          at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
          at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
          at ij.IJ.runUserPlugIn(IJ.java:226)
          at ij.IJ.runPlugIn(IJ.java:192)
          at ij.IJ.runPlugIn(IJ.java:181)
          at Eyesis_Correction.main(Eyesis_Correction.java:10089)
  ```

### System information

- **Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow)**:
  Yes. The stock example script/programs does not exist.
- **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04)**:
  Linux Ubuntu 16.04
- **Mobile device (e.g. iPhone 8, Pixel 2, Samsung Galaxy) if the issue happens on mobile device**:
  N/A
- **TensorFlow installed from (source or binary)**:
  binary via pom.xml:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.tensorflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>libtensorflow</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.tensorflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>libtensorflow_jni_gpu</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.0</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- **TensorFlow version (use command below)**:
  1.10.0
- **Python version**:
  3.5.2
- **Bazel version (if compiling from source)**:
  N/A
- **GCC/Compiler version (if compiling from source)**:
  N/A
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**:
  9.0
- **GPU model and memory**:
  GeForce GTX 750 Ti
- **Exact command to reproduce**:
  N/A

### Links

- [infer_qcds_graph_01.py](https://github.com/Elphel/python3-imagej-tiff/blob/master/infer_qcds_graph_01.py) - script that stores/restores the model and runs inference
- [TensorflowExamplePlugin.java](https://git.elphel.com/Elphel/imagej-elphel/blob/gpu/src/main/java/TensorflowExamplePlugin.java) - ImageJ plugin code

### Updates

#### Update 1: opBuilder

Trying to use opBuilder to init results in error:

code:

```
Output oValue = bundle.graph().opBuilder("Const", "rv_stage1_out").setAttr("dtype", tensorVal.dataType()).setAttr("value", tensorVal).build().output(0);
```

error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate node name in graph: 'rv_stage1_out'
```

#### Update 2: GLOBAL_VARIABLES vs LOCAL_VARIABLES collections.

While in Python, adding the variable to GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES collection (while it was only in GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES) seems to have fixed the error.

#### Update 3: Possible solution

```
builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess,[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],main_op=tf.local_variables_initializer())
```

See [tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22362](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22362).